Why lines variable is 0?
I've created wc like program and when i tried to do line counting, it shows as 0. The code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE* file;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    //printf("%d\n", argc);

    if (argc == 2) {
        file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        char chr;

        if (!file) {
            perror("Error opening file");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);
        int bytes = ftell(file);    // bytes

        int lines = 0;
        chr = getc(file);
        while (chr != EOF) {
            chr = getc(file);
            if (chr = '\n')
                lines = lines + 1;
        }
        
        int words = 0;

        printf("%d %d %d %s\n", lines, words, bytes, argv[1]);

        fclose(file);
    } else {
        printf("Usage:\n");
        printf("%s <-cml> <filename>\n", argv[0]);
        printf("%s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
    }

    return 0;
}
}

I tried changing loops from for to while and do..while but didn't worked. The file is opened successfully and compiler doesn't show any errors or warnings.

How do you know the file opened successfully? You don't show the open code.

You don't show the type of chr — it should be an int and not a char.

Edit the question to provide a [mre].

The code as-posted produces an infinite loop. This is because the if statement is coded as an assignment statement, not a comparison. Change = to ==. But this doesn't explain your suggestion that the program does exit (i.e. not loop forever), but lines is zero. You'll need to include more of your code (preferably a fully compilable and runnable program).

@StreveFord oh thank you i didn't saw that

The variable used to hold getc* must be int

@TeenProgrammer if (chr = '\n') --> Save time, enable all compiler warnings.

@TeenProgrammer, If the file only contains 3 bytes: "abc", would you consider that 1 or 0 lines?

There are a few small issues with the code, but I'll just focus on three and especially the main one which I believe is the usage of fseek().
Specifically, SEEK_END caused the file pointer to move to the end of the file. When that is done, the code really can't read from the file at all.  I see why it was done -- to get the file length -- but we neglected to set the file pointer back to the start of the file via SEEK_SET.
And so this explains why lines variable was always zero, in answer to your main question.  It was because no bytes were read at all, as far as I can tell.  When no bytes are read, the linefeed \n will never be seen, and hence the lines variable will always be zero.
The 2nd item -- arguably kind of minor because you probably did declare it somewhere (I guess) -- is that we now declare chr.
The 3rd item is the comparison if(chr = '\n') which is actually an assignment. This is a comparison -> if(chr == '\n').
And so here is just the applicable repaired code block/snippet, for sake of brevity:
    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END); 
    int bytes = ftell(file); 
    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_SET);  // fixed fseek().  Set to start of file
    int chr;       //not declared before?  Fixed
    int lines = 0;
    chr = getc(file);
    while (chr != EOF) {  
        chr = getc(file); // Should be able to read some bytes now...
        if (chr == '\n')  // Comparison, now fixed
            lines = lines + 1;
    }


Minor: int bytes = ftell(file); better as long bytes = ftell(file); as no need to truncated the ftell() result.  Suggest long lines = 0; for like reasons.  No need for L in fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);
